# ColdFusion 9 set decimal type for cfqueryparam?

Tags: coldfusion, decimal, coldfusion-9, cfqueryparam

I have few form fields where user can enter `whole` numbers, `decimal` numbers and both types can be positive or negative. In other words they can enter something like this:

```
1 or 0.9 or 5.6745 or -10 or -0.9 or -10.5435
```

I'm wondering what I should use in my `cfqueryparam` on cfsqltype? I tried decimal but looks like that is not supported in ColdFusion 9. Is there any other option or I should use `varchar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option that matches the column in your database. By selecting the correct value, Coldfusion will try to validate and format the value before it is sent off to the database driver.

With fix precision types `cf_sql_numeric` and `cf_sql_decimal` you need to also specify the scale (number of decimal places) your column accepts. By default the scale is 0, and will only store an integer number. Once again check your database for the scale.

For non precision types such as `cf_sql_float` no scale should be specified and the full value is sent off to the database.

Full list of data types can be found in the [Adobes docs.](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html)